# How to get figure size and fontsize right for PDFs exported from matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, font-size

I need to generate figures that fit into a particular width and use a particular font size, preferably without post-processing the pdf file.

On my system, the default GUI backend is 'TkAgg' and the default font size is 12.0 as reported by the `get_fontsize()` method on a text object. When I generate a figure using

```
f = pyplot.figure(figsize=(2.0,2.0))
f.text(0.5,0.5,'TEXT')
pyplot.show()
```

and save as PDF, the figure size is too large. `pdfinfo` reports

```
Creator:        matplotlib 1.1.1rc, http://matplotlib.sf.net
Producer:       matplotlib pdf backend
CreationDate:   Sat May 25 10:52:02 2013
Tagged:         no
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      196.2 x 153 pts
File size:      9357 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.4
```

196.2 [pt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28typography%29#Current_DTP_point_system) == 2.725 inch

However, if I resize the figure to be 2 inch wide, the fontsize matches (visually) with 12pt LaTeX fonts.

Contrarily, skipping the GUI produces a figure with the right dimensions, but fonts too large:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('PDF')
f = pyplot.figure(figsize=(2.0,2.0))
f.text(0.5,0.5,'TEXT')
f.savefig('test.pdf')

Creator:        matplotlib 1.1.1rc, http://matplotlib.sf.net
Producer:       matplotlib pdf backend
CreationDate:   Sat May 25 10:50:42 2013
Tagged:         no
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      144 x 144 pts
File size:      9254 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.4
```

144 pt == 2.0 inch

The Cairo backend produces the same result. Adding `f.set_size_inches((2,2))` doesn't change anything either.

Is there a recipe to get font and figure sizes just right with matplotlib?

Comment: did you get this sorted out?

Comment: @tcaswell. I'll post an update or answer as soon as I know for sure what works (with the latest version of matplotlib).

Comment: Two years down the line; Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2):

check your `.matplotlibrc` and look for `sivefig.bbox`, make sure it is commented out, or set to something that is *not* `tight`.

You can try:

```
fig.savefig('so.png', bbox_inches=matplotlib.transforms.Bbox(np.array(((0, 0), (2, 2)))))
```

which explictly sets the bounding box.

That said, if you do not have anything in your `.matplotlibrc`, you should report this as a bug.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's a bug. I'm using matplotlib 1.1.1-rc1, the latest version available for Ubuntu Precise 12.04 LTS. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use fig.set_size_inches as you can give exactly the physical size of the pdf.

Comment: and make sure to _not_ use a `tight` bounding box.

Comment: This does not help. I changed my question accordingly.

Comment: @tcaswell I have not explicitly set a "tight" bounding box. If this should be the problem, how do I avoid tight bounding boxes?